# Webapps in Android: Get new content without website reload

Tags: android, web-applications

I have an android app which is a wrapper around my mobile site. We have a site that changes everyday, and I’d like to have a method by which I can notify the user that there’s new content to be had, or just reload it programmatically.

This obviously happens when the app relaunches, but sometimes users will keep the app in sleep mode and re-open it the next day and they see a stale version of the website. Is there any way around without going native? One method I thought off was using a push notification to reload the app (i.e. use GCM to tell the app to reload the page) except I don’t want to push a new version as this would require permission changes and that would break auto-updating. I though of using socket.io for the task as I'm already using it in my app but I don’t think it'll work if the app is the background (will it? I’m an android newbie)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When the application returns from sleep - onResume() of the activity life cycle may be invoked. If you reload the webview on this listener, that should resolve it.
Unless i am missing something very significant, this simple solution might work.